# Compiler for language with scoping using bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, lalr

I am trying to make a compiler for custom C-based language that supports scoping of variables using C++ and flex + bison. I have made a lexer and parser, but I am having trouble solving the issue with scoping. I have implemented semantic actions in bison parser file e.g.

```
while_stmt  :   WHILE LEFT_PAREN expr RIGHT_PAREN LEFT_CBRACE stmts RIGHT_CBRACE { $$ = new WhileStatement($3, *$6); }
            ;
```

What I am having a problem with is finding a moment when to put the new symbol table onto context symbol table stack. Since it is a bottom-up parser I don't know when the new block starts, just when it ends, after reduction is performed and it is too late for me. The code that I put behind rule is extecuted after the reduction.

How can be this solved using bison? I am brainstorming for a while now with no solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In a compiler scoping is a semantic action and is not normally handled at the parsing level but at a later stage during a semantic tree walk.

If you try and do it at parse time you get into the problems you have explained.
Parsing is only intended to check that the sequences of tokens match the grammar. Everything else should be performed from the parse tree created at parse time.

This is not a bison specific question. It applies to any compiler and parser (that uses context free grammars).

Comment: Few minutes ago I have found out about http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions.html#Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions what seems to solve what I am trying to achieve. I have implemented scoped symbol tables and if I am able to put the action into mid-rule, then I can put new symbol table whenever LEFT_CBRACE appears and pop it from the stack whenever RIGHT_CBRACE terminates the block. I am currently implementing it and let you know how it ended up.